# Adding Customer Address / Quote Field Enterprise Only?

Tags: magento2, magento-community

I am struggling to add a field to checkout addresses that persists to the database, I have found this question where Magento insist on knowing the version of Magento and state that the feature is only available in Enterprise, I had no idea this was a requirement for such a customisation.

Does anyone know if what I am trying to do is possible in community edition?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a this example module to add a Extra Address Field to the Checkout.

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-ExtraCheckoutAddressFields

Comment: You made no mention of the core of my question which is whether this is possible with Community Edition.

Comment: The given example is a module for Community